# Android 11 - Wireless Debugging turns off when phones' display turns off

Tags: android, mobile-development, redmi-device

I have been having this problem with my **Redmi Note 9 Pro**. Whenever I turn on wireless debugging, it turns off whenever the device goes to sleep. I have checked WiFi settings for **turn off WiFi during sleep** but did not find any such option in the MIUI Wifi options. I reset my phone few months back, and the problem was gone. But now it is back, and I cant afford to reset my phone every now and then.

Edit: I am using Wireless Debugging option in Android 11 and not the `adb tcpip` method.